# How to save position in an array and a view count using UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, save, nsuserdefaults

first time poster here. I want to save the position in an array and a view count individually for each item in the array. I have a struct which handles the data here;

```
import Foundation

struct Vocab {
   
    let vocabTitle: String
    let vocabHiragana: String
    let englishTranslation: String
}
```

I then call it using a separate swift file with a struct:

```
import Foundation
var vocabNumber = 0

struct VocabBuilder {
    let testVocab = [ Vocab(vocabTitle: "上達", vocabHiragana: "じょうたつ", englishTranslation: "Improvement"),
                      Vocab(vocabTitle: "乗り越える", vocabHiragana: "のりこえる", englishTranslation: "To Push Through"),
                      Vocab(vocabTitle: "耐久性", vocabHiragana: "たいきゅうせい", englishTranslation: "Durability"),
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "促す", vocabHiragana: "うながす", englishTranslation: "To doubt"),
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "一律", vocabHiragana: "いちりつ", englishTranslation: "Across the board"),
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "押し切り", vocabHiragana: "おしきり", englishTranslation: "Objection"),
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "打ち込む", vocabHiragana: "うちこむ", englishTranslation: "To input") ,
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "溶け込む", vocabHiragana: "とけこむ", englishTranslation: "To get used to"),
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "放り込む", vocabHiragana: "ほうりこむ", englishTranslation: "Throw into (something)"),
    Vocab(vocabTitle: "後継者", vocabHiragana: "こうけいしゃ", englishTranslation: "Successor") ]

func getVocab() -> String {   
    return testVocab[vocabNumber].vocabTitle
}

func getHiragana() -> String {
    return testVocab[vocabNumber].vocabHiragana
}

func getEnglishTranslation() -> String {
    return testVocab[vocabNumber].englishTranslation
}

mutating func nextVocab() {
    NSLog("Before", "\(vocabNumber)")
    vocabNumber = (vocabNumber + Int.random(in: 0...9)) % testVocab.count
    NSLog("After", "\(vocabNumber)")
}

}
```

The problem I have is that in my main ViewController is that I want to save the position in an array including all the functions that return strings into the ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var greySquare: UIView!
    var answerBox: UILabel!
    var continueButton: UIButton!
    var inputButton: UIButton!
    var rightWrongAnswerBox: UILabel!
    let rightWrongText = String()
    var englishTranslationBox: UILabel!
    var hiraganaBox: UILabel!
    var viewCountBox: UILabel!
    
    var userInputs: String?
   
    var viewedVocab = [String]()
    
    var pictureViewCount: Int = 0
    
    var vocabInfo = VocabBuilder() //create var to handle the struct info
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
       
            func loadView() {
            view = UIView()
                
                view.backgroundColor = .white
```

// initialised views for each box here

```
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               // had the constraints here for the views.
                ])
                
            
        loadView()

        loadUI()
             
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        //let savedData = pictureViewCount
            
        if let savedViewCount = defaults.value(forKey: "picVC") as? Int {
                
        print("savedValue: \(savedViewCount + 1)")
            
            }
        
            }
    
 
    func loadUI() {
       
        answerBox.text = vocabInfo.getVocab()
       
        englishTranslationBox.text = vocabInfo.getEnglishTranslation()
        
        hiraganaBox.textColor = .white
        
        hiraganaBox.text = vocabInfo.getHiragana()
   
        viewCountBox.text = ("View Count: \(pictureViewCount)"}
            
       }

        rightWrongAnswerBox.text = "Try and Remember!"
        rightWrongAnswerBox.textColor = .black
        
    pictureViewCount += 1
        save()
        
}    
    func submit(answer: String) {
        
        
        if hiraganaBox.text == answer {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Correct!", message: "Go to the next word!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
             present(ac, animated: true)
            hiraganaBox.textColor = .black
            rightWrongAnswerBox.text = "Correct!"
            rightWrongAnswerBox.textColor = .green
            
        } else if hiraganaBox.text != answer {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Incorrect!", message: "Give it another go.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
             present(ac, animated: true)
            rightWrongAnswerBox.text = "Incorrect"
            rightWrongAnswerBox.textColor = .red
            
        }      
        
    }
    
    @objc func answerAttempt (_ sender: UIButton) {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "What is this word in Hiragana?", message: "Enter your answer into the box below", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField()
        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default){
            [weak ac] action in// make a closure to handle text field.
            guard let answer = ac?.textFields?[0].text else { return }
            self.submit(answer: answer)
         
        }
        ac.addAction(submitAction)
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func continueToNextWord (_ sender: UIButton) {

        vocabInfo.nextVocab()
       
        loadUI()
       
       
}
    func save(){
        //let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        
        //if let saveNumber = try?jsonEncoder.encode(pictureViewCount) { 
           // let savedWord = try?jsonEncoder.encode(vocabInfo.getVocab())
            
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let savedData = pictureViewCount
        
        let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "picVC")

        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(currentCount + 1, forKey: "picVC")
            defaults.set(saveData, forKey: "pictureViewCount")
            defaults.setValue(savedWord, forKey: "savedWord")
        } else {
          print("Failed to save View Count.")
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**
The issue I have is that I'm just not sure after looking at tutorials where saving arrays. What I've tried is using JSON to save and encode and decode the user defaults to keep the position in the array loaded up when the app is closed and loaded again. Also I tried to increase the picture view count for each item in the array, which is randomly loaded up and save it as an integer but it just increases the view count when the continueToNextWord function is called.
[View Controller as it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXBFy.png) so when I press the next word button I want it to save the view count on the randomly shown words and assign it to that item.

I'm gonna try some different ways to get the UserDefaults working but any help will be appreciated.

If its not clear I can also use DMs.

Comment: Not related to your question but don't use `value(forKey:)` Use `integer(forKey:)` as you are already doing somewhere else in your code. And don't use `setValue(, forKey:)`. Use `set(_ value: Any, forKey:)`

Comment: Ah I see, I should be using specific types instead of value here? Also sure I’ll replace so the type should be Any. Thanks

Comment: No need to change your types to Any. Just use the `set` method instead of `setValue`.